# How to handle related stores with Svelte

Tags: state, store, svelte

I have a store with a list of entities, and another Store with and object that include one of those entities.

I want changes in the first store to be reactively reflected on the second.

I'll provide a quick example with a list of items and a list of invoices

```js
export type Invoice = {
  id: string
  customer: string
  items: InvoiceItem[]
}

export type InvoiceItem = {
  id: string
  name: string
  price: number
}
```

Whenever the name or price of an invoice item is updated I'd like all the related Invoices to also be updated.

I created this very simple example (repl available [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/37ee8fc982f342eebadaaff34ae1df3c?version=3.44.2)) but in order for the $invoices store to be updated I have to issue a $invoices = $invoices whenever the $items store changes.

Another more elegant way to do it is to subscribe to the items store and from there update the invoices store, like this:

```
items.subscribe(_ => invoices.update(data => data))
```

```html
<script>
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store'
    
    let item1 = { id: 'item-01', name: 'Item number 01', price: 100 }
    let item2 = { id: 'item-02', name: 'Item number 02', price: 200 }
    let item3 = { id: 'item-03', name: 'Item number 03', price: 300 }
    let items = writable([item1, item2, item3])
    
    let invoices = writable([
        { id: 'invoice-0', customer: 'customer1', items: [item1, item3] }
    ])
    
    items.subscribe(_ => invoices.update(data => data))     // refresh invoices store whenever an item is changed

    const updateItem1 = () => {
        $items[0].price = $items[0].price + 10
        // $invoices = $invoices    // alternatively, manually tell invoices store that something changed every time I change and item!!!
    }
</script>

<button on:click={updateItem1}>update item 1 price</button>
<hr />
<textarea rows="18">{JSON.stringify($invoices, null, 2)}</textarea>
<textarea rows="18">{JSON.stringify($items, null, 2)}</textarea>
```

Is this the best way to handle this kind of scenario?

---

Update: thanks to the great answers and comments I came out with this more complete example: see this [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/d9fb573137cc468b8efa256701d39f6b?version=3.44.2)

I added some functionality that I hope will serve as basis for similar common scenarios

This is how my store api ended up:

```js
// items.js

items.subscribe // read only store
items.reset()
items.upsert(item) // updates the specified item, creates a new one if it doesn't exist


// invoices.js

invoices.subscribe // read only store
invoices.add(invocieId, customer, date) // adds a new invoice
invoices.addLine(invoiceId, itemId, quantity)
invoices.getInvoice(invoice) // get a derived store for that particular invoice


invoice.subscribe // read only store
invoice.addLine(itemId, quantity)
```

A few highlights

- invoices now has a `lines` array, each with an item and a quantity
- invoices is a derived store that calculate total for each line and for the whole invoice
- implementes an upsert method in items
- in order to update invoices whenever an item is modified I run `items.subscribe(() => set(_invoices))`
- also created a derived store to get a specific invoice

Comment: Clearly in favor of the subscription approach, as it articulates your intent better (on top of it being more elegant, as you pointed out), i.e. "have the invoice store subscribe to the items store in order for changes in the latter to trigger an update in the former".
That being said, invoice & items is a poor example choice. In a real world app, items would be immutable (at least in the scope of a given invoice) and likely come from an outside source. Only their quantity will change and that data would be located in the invoice itself, so there would really be no need for an items store ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, please have a llok at the updated working example: https://svelte.dev/repl/d9fb573137cc468b8efa256701d39f6b?version=3.44.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution depends on whether or not you need `items` independently (one item can be part of multiple invoices) or if it can be part of the invoices. If they can be one big blob, I would create `invoices` as a store and provide methods to update specific invoices. The `items` store then would be derived from the `invoices`.

```js
// invoices.ts
const _invoices = writable([]);
// public API of your invoices store
export const invoices = {
  subscribe: _invoices.subscribe,
  addItemToInvoice: (invoideId, item) => {...},
  ..
};
// derived items:
const items = derived(invoices, $invoices => flattenAllInvoiceItems($invoice));
```

However, if they need to be separate - or if it is easier to handle item updates that way -, then I would only store the IDs of the items in the invoice store and create a derived store which uses invoices+items to create the full invoices.

```js
// items.ts
const _items = writable([]);
// public API of your items store
export const items = {
  subscribe: _items.subscribe,
  update: (item) => {...},
  ...
};
// invoices.ts
import { items } from './items';
const _invoices = writable([]);
// public API of your invoices store
export const invoices = {
  // Assuming you never want the underlying _invoices state avialable publicly
  subscribe: derived([_invoices, items], ([$invoices, $items]) => mergeItemsIntoInvoices($invoices, $items)),
  addItemToInvoice: (invoideId, item) => {...},
  ..
};
```

In both cases you can use `invoices` and `items` in your Svelte components like you want, interact with a nice public API and the derived stores will ensure everything is synched.

Comment: Excellent answer, it gave me a couple great ideas, I created a more elaborate examples with some of your ideas: https://svelte.dev/repl/d9fb573137cc468b8efa256701d39f6b?version=3.44.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use a derived store like this:

```
let pipe = derived([invoices, items], ([$invoices, $items]) => {
    return $invoices;
})
```

So $pipe will return an updated invoice if the invoice was changed.

$pipe will be triggered bij both stores ($items and $invoice) but only produces a result if the invoice was changed. So $pipe will not produce a result when an item changes which is not part of the invoice.

**Update.** I expected no result of $pipe when $invoices does not change as is the case for a writeable store. But a derived store callback will always run if $invoices or $items changes.

So we have to check if $invoices changes and use set only if we have a change.

```
let cache = "";
let pipe = derived([invoices, items], ([$invoices, $items], set) => {
    if (JSON.stringify($invoices) !== cache) {
        cache = JSON.stringify($invoices); 
        set($invoices);
    }
}, {})
```